# Proof closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition, especially that $m+(-n) \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $m\in\mathbb{N}, n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: ring-theory

I need help with the following task:
*Prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition*

We define the set of integers as $\mathbb{Z}$= {${n:n\in\mathbb{N}}$} $\cup$ {$0$} $\cup$ {$-n:n\in\mathbb{N}$}. Also $0$ $\notin$ $\mathbb{N}$

The additon of integers, defined as the sum of two integers (or the result we get on adding two or more integers), has the following properties:

A1) $x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$  $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$

A2) $x+y=y+x$ $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$

A3) There exists exactly one element $0$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$ with the property $x+0=x$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}$

A4) For each $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists exactly one element $-x\in\mathbb{Z}$ with the property $x+(-x)=0$

It seems to be a very easy task. Unfortunately I don't have a clue how to prove the case that $$m+(-n) \in \mathbb{Z}   ,( m\in\mathbb{N}, n\in\mathbb{N})$$
I found posts here were people simply answered, yeah m+(-n) = m-n and the difference of two natural numbers is an integer. But without a proof, this is not sufficient and unfortunately I didn't found any proof for this. We obviousle have to differentiate between thre cases: m>n, m=n, m<n. I wanted to prove this task with help of induction, since it helped me for my proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed under addition. But in this case, it gets complicated.

Anyone an idea, how to prove this easily? I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: You gave the definition of $\mathbb Z$, but not the definition of addition of integers.

Comment: "The addition of integers, defined as the sum of two integers (or the result we get on adding two or more integers" - this is extremely circular and doesn't define a thing. You must instead construct $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb N$ in the usual manner (find it on Wiki) and observe the construction of addition. Then you can show the result. As it stands you don't have any definitions that make the question provable. In fact, axioms $A1-A4$ assume that $x+y\in\Bbb Z$ implicitly already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at the very least you should assume this property from the naturals, this is the one derived directly from the successors definition.

$$m\ge n\implies \exists a\in\mathbb N\mid m=n+a$$

Then you can proceed from the axioms you gave:

$m+(-n)=(n+a)+(-n)\,\stackrel{A_1}{=}\,(n+(-n))+a\,\stackrel{A_4}{=}\,0+a\,\stackrel{A_2}{=}\,a+0\,\stackrel{A_3}{=}\,a\in\mathbb Z$

For the case $m\le n\ $ or $\,n=m+a$ you have to prove first that: $$-(m+a)=(-m)+(-a)$$

$(m+a)+(-m)+(-a)=(m+(-m))+(a+(-a))=0+0=0$

And then proceed the same way as before:

$m+(-n)=m+(-m)+(-a)=0+(-a)=(-a)+0=(-a)\in\mathbb Z$